# Websphere app migration from 7.0 to 8.5 changing force as unpack WebService

Tags: websphere, axis, apache-axis, websphere-8, websphere-7

I have a java application that currently runs on WebSphere 7.0, in this app, no matter what value I send in the xmlns:ws namespace, the system accepts it normally.

When I migrated to websphere 8.5, the system only unmarshalls if I use exactly the same namespace. This is causing a problem because I have a lot of consumers and they are sending different namespaces...

From what I saw, the error occurs because in axis2, instead of using the DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller class, it is using DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller

I can't force it to use DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller

Has anyone experienced this problem?

I hope you can help me find how to use the DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller class.